# HTTPS Ingress with Istio and SDS not working (returns 404) when I configure multiple Gateways

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, istio

When I configure multiple (gateway - virtual service) pairs in a namespace, each pointing to basic HTTP services, only one service becomes accessable. Calls to the other (typically, the second configured) return 404. If the first gateway is deleted, the second service then becomes accesible

I raised a github issue a few weeks ago  ( https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/20661 ) that contains all my configuration but no response to date. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong (if anything) ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on that [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/12500)

> The gateway port names have to be unique, if they are sharing the same port. Thats the only way we differentiate different RDS blocks. We went through this motion earlier as well. I wouldn't rock this boat unless absolutely necessary.

More about the issue [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/12556)

Checked it on [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-mount/#configure-traffic-for-the-bookinfo-com-host), and in fact if you configure multiple gateways name of the first one is https, but second is https-bookinfo.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: httpbin-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "httpbin.example.com"
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https-bookinfo
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-bookinfo-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-bookinfo-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "bookinfo.com"
```

---

### **EDIT**

That's weird, but I have another idea.

There is a [github pull](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/12556) which have the following line in pilot:

```
routeName := gatewayRDSRouteName(s, config.Namespace)
```

> This change adds namespace scoping to Gateway port names by appending
>   namespace suffix to the HTTPS RDS routes. Port names still have to be
>   unique within the namespace boundaries, but this change makes adding
>   more specific scoping rather trivial.

Could you try make 2 namespaces like in below example

**EXAMPLE**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  labels:
    name: httpbin
    istio-injection: enabled
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nodejs
  labels:
    name: nodejs
    istio-injection: enabled
```

And deploy everything( deployment,service,virtual service,gateway) in proper namespace and let me know if that works?

---

Could You try change the hosts from "*" to some names? It's only thing that came to my mind besides trying serverCertficate and privateKey but from the comments I assume you have already try it.

Let me know if that help.

Comment: I tried making the gateway port names unique. It didn't help. Only one of the gateways will work. They can't coexist when using sds . I'll try with the old method (specifying serverCertficate and privateKey)

Comment: I do notice that the wrong server certificate is presented to the call that fails. In the following snippet, it should be CN=some.host.com ... . 

```
$ curl -v  -k   --noproxy "*"  https://cmsplavm224.oma2hpe.lan:31918/status/418
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=other.host.com,O=Dis,L=Springfield,ST=Denial,C=US
...
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Gist of the gateway config etc is at https://gist.github.com/balamuru/117a527a4797efa3cf7d78d7a119a10d

Comment: Created a formal github issue at https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/21077 (against the latest release 1.4.4)

Comment: I think it's the wildcard in the hosts field that is causing the issue. I've replicated the issue for both SDS as well as file mounted secrets with wildcarded hosts in the same namespace. If I explicitly specify hosts when multiple gateways exist in the same namespace, then calls work . I'll try defining the applications with wildcards in different namespaces and see what happens